# How to create a new site collection and open it in SPD?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, site-collection, virtual-machine

Using a virtual machine (Oracle VirtualBox with Windows 7 and Sharepoint Server 2010), when I create a new `site-collection` in SCA, I can't open it with Sharepoint Designer.

When I try, it says:

> Microsoft Sharepoint Designer does not support editing non-Sharepoint
>   sites.

Now, that's a bit strange to me!  I can navigate to the "sharepoint site" just fine in Firefox and IE!

I can confirm that the Sharepoint Designer Settings for the site collection are all set to allow the use of SPD.  And I am admin everywhere.

The "Home" site is called `http://myserver` and the new site collection is at `http://myserver/sites/thesite`, where `/sites/` is the managed url path that came default with Sharepoint.

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I stumbled around and finally got it.

Go to "Manage Web Applications" in Sharepoint Central Administration.  Click on "Sharepoint - 80" or "myserver" or whatever you named the server and then click on the `Managed Paths` button.

Now check the box for "sites" and click okay. ( You don't have to worry about "Add a New Path".)

That must update a setting somewhere, because it makes the site available to Sharepoint Designer.